# WPF Tooltip data binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create tool tip for ListView rows.
Current data structure used to generate listview:

```
public class Map
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<Difficulty> Difficulties{get;set;}
}

public class Difficulty
{
    public int ID{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

// Items to list are added like.
ListView.Items.Add(new Map(){....});
```

This is what I have with tool tip XAML code:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Difficulties}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ID}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

It all works, but what I need is to display **Name** from **Map**, not **Difficulty**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Text="{Binding DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
```